# Can Primefaces Push work across archives?

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm trying to get PrimeFaces Push working. The web side is packaged in a WAR and the MDBs are packaged within a JAR, and these are inside an EAR. I'm using the following components.

Glassfish 3.1.2
PrimeFaces 3.4.1
Firefox 10.0.7
Linux

I have the following code within a message-driven bean of a JAR and each time the MDB receives a message, I'm expecting growl messages to display within the web app, however, that's not happening. I have the WAR and JARs packaged within an EAR. Could it be that this doesn't work across containers or have something to do with the way I'm packaging?

```
pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
pushContext.push("/test", new FacesMessage("Test Summary", "Test Detail"));
```

Here's the web.xml for a war.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>ws://localhost:8080</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And here's the index.xhtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(msg) {
        msg.severity = 'info';
        growl.show([msg]);
    }
</script>

<p:growl id="growl" widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true"/>

<p:socket channel="/test" onMessage="handleMessage"/>
```

When I invoke the pushContext.push() from the MDB, I get the println() output that shows everything executing all the way through the onMessage() of the MDB. No errors, all looks fine.

I just don't see anything happening in the index.xhtml page (i.e. javascript messageHandle).

I'm not using Maven so I wasn't sure how to translate the pom.xml. My EAR looks like the following.

```
.
|-- META-INF
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- application.xml
|-- ejb.jar
|-- app1.war
|-- lib
|   |-- atmosphere-cometd-1.0.2.jar
|   |-- atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.0.2.jar
|   |-- atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.2.jar
|   |-- atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.2.jar
|   |-- atmosphere-runtime-1.0.2.jar
|   |-- primefaces-3.4.1.jar
|   |-- redmond-1.0.8.jar
|   `-- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
`-- otherapp.war
```

I don't have primefaces.jar within my EJB, but it is in the lib dir (as shown above) and where I have this in the application.xml.

```
<module>
    <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
</module>

<library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

Comment: this is how i do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294909/access-pushcontext-from-ejb-tier so it is possible

Comment: But the question is how you setup the classpath of the .jar i think. Do you have a serverlog of what happens when you invoke the pushContext.push() from the mdb?

Comment: I updated the question with your latest comments in mind.

Comment: do you get ppush to work if you call it from a managed bean? nothing in the webconsole of the browser?

Comment: The only other diff i really see is that i had to add primefaces/atmosphere to the classpath in manifest of ejb.jar

Comment: Apparently I have something else wrong because I tried it from a backing bean, and though I see no errors, I don't see growl notifications.

Comment: I found this error in the Firefox error console  `Error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/test/primepush/notifications?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Cache-Date=0.
Source File: http://localhost:8080/test/javax.faces.resource/push/push.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces
Line: 1`